# Excel - Find the name with the biggest avg

Tags: excel

which function I can use to find a string (person name) who has the biggest value of average

Example: I have 3 persons , Bob is holding an avg of 30 , Maya is holding an avg of 70 and Natasha is holding an avg of 25
now I need a function to search the biggest avg and return the name of that person

thank you

Comment: Something along the lines of `VLOOKUP` or perhaps `INDEX` and `MATCH` can be used to, well, lookup values (including the max average which can be determined by `MAX`).

Comment: upon web search & research...  please share where exactly that you stuck aat when applying it.. ( :